# How to select all information of a group in sqlite3

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to get all information on one user from a databse called Users. This databse will have multiple users in it and it is important it gets the right information about a user. This is how my databse is created.

```
def NewDataBase():
        cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
    userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    sirname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    recID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
    ''')
```

I then have this

```
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
except:
    print("error")

"""
Query all rows in the users table
:param conn: the Connection object
:return: Connection object or None
"""
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

I Get this data from it

```
(1, 'NewuSer', 'new', 'uSer', 'new', 'new', '1111')
(2, 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g')
```

How would i be able to select one of the rows using the first value which is the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick.

```
username = ('Dextron',)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', username)
user = cur.fetchone()
```

You can read more about sqlite3 api [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", username)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.

Comment: Try changing it for single quotes when assigning the username value.

Comment: Or instead do, `username = 'Dextron'` and `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username, ))`.

Comment: Also execute() method expects a sequence as second parameter. If you supply it as a string it will fail.

Comment: How would you seperate them into different strings and print each one of them seperetly